# Box of Grade A's?

Tags: meaning, interpretation

On an episode of Seinfeld, Kramer says

"they ambushed me with a box of grade A's".

[image]

What is that?

I was unable to find a translation to that.

Comment: You watched it, I didn't. But looking at the state of the guy, I'd imagine it was a box of "top-class flour bombs" or similar (perhaps even more metaphorically, a box of top-notch *snowballs* - I can't really tell from the still clip here).

Comment: it does not appear he being ambushed, just he saying that. I have realized now that he may be talking about class A eggs, I mean the largest ones.

Comment: It certainly looks to *me* like he was "ambushed" in some way! What's all that white stuff? OIC  - they're ***Grade A eggs*** (the white bits look like ***eggshell***, and there's a yellowish bit that looks like egg yolk below his right collar. But like I said, you watched it.

Comment: yes, I have realized that a few moments ago. Please make your comment a question.

Comment: If you meant @FumbleFingers could make their comment an *answer*, then I agree ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained by a line later in the episode:

Kramer: Well, that's odd, 'cause I feel perfectly at peace with the world- uh! eggs! you! Serenity now, serenity now, serenity now.

Someone threw eggs at Kramer. Eggs are often labeled “Grade A” as an indication that they are high quality.

Comment: I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To *ambush* someone is to attack them from a concealed position, to trap, to surprise.

*Grade A* describes something of the highest quality.

What was in the box was of good quality, and it probably made the ambush better.

Comment: Feasibly the ambush would have been "better" if the eggs were "Grade A", 'cos lesser quality eggs might include some with weakened or broken shells, which might have made them harder to throw accurately. But I expect the only reason for mentioning it at all is the quirky implication that "suitable for use by kids pelting their enemies" might be more important than *price* when selecting the missiles to be thrown. At least if they're Grade A, they're probably not ***rotten*** (which could be truly unpleasant, like being pelted with faeces; no longer "funny").